# Circular Progressbar showing square corners

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I have this issue, My progress drawable that I use for a progressbar in activity, works perfectly normal. But once I use the same drawable resource to display progressbar in my recyclerview these corners around progressbar show up.

Here is my progressbar view code:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/newshit"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBarMain"/>
```

And here is the custom progressbar drawable.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="270"
  android:toDegrees="270">
  <shape
      android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
      android:shape="ring"
      android:thickness="15dp"
      android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

      <gradient
          android:angle="0"
          android:endColor="@color/green"
          android:centerColor="#f6e41a"
          android:startColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
          android:type="sweep"
          android:useLevel="false" />

       </shape>
       </rotate>
```

[image: Custom Progressbar (Determinate) showing weird corners in recyclerview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this sample.

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="270"
  android:toDegrees="270">
  <shape
      android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
      android:shape="ring"
      android:thickness="8"
      android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

      <gradient
          android:angle="0"
          android:endColor="@color/green"
          android:centerColor="#f6e41a"
          android:startColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
          android:type="sweep"
          android:useLevel="false" />

  </shape>
</rotate>
```

Comment: you are my hero. This works. Can you tell me what was the issue?

Comment: I modified this two lines android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5" and  android:thickness="15dp"